# Need help writing a SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have the following tables.

> **Customer_table**
>   Customer_ID | Last name | First Name | City_ID | Region_ID | Country_ID
>
> **Country_table**
>  Country_ID | Country
>
> **Region_table**
>  Region_ID | Region | Country_ID
>
> **City_table**
>  City_ID | City | Region_ID | Country_ID

I need to find the number of customers city-wise,ie, for all countries, for all regions in the countries, for all cities in the region, i need to get the no. of customers in each city.

For example, I wrote the following SQL to get the no. of customers in each country:

```
SELECT a.country_id , b.country,count(*) 
FROM Customer_Table a INNER JOIN Country_Table b
ON a.country_id = b.country_id
GROUP BY b.country , b.country_id ;
```

and to get the no. of customers in each region for a particular country:

```
SELECT a.region_id , b.region , count(*)
FROM Customers_table a INNER JOIN Region_Table b
ON a.region_id = b.region_id
WHERE a.country_id ='USA' AND b.country_id ='USA'
GROUP BY region_id , country ;
```

What I need to find is the number of customers city-wise,ie, for all countries, for all regions in the countries, for all cities in the region, i need to get the no. of customers in each city, something like

```
Country | Region  |       City     | no.of customers
  USA   |   CA    |  San Francisco |    53
  USA   |   CA    |  Los Angeles   |    45
  USA   |   CA    |  Sacramento    |    16
  USA   |   WA    |  Seattle       |    46
  USA   |   WA    |  Olympia       |    9
  UK    | England |  London        |    89
  UK    | England |  Nottingham    |    71
  UK    | Wales   |  Cardiff       |    69
  UK    | Wales   |  Newport       |    23

  ..................and so on for other countries.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tables have redundant info

since they are linked, each table only needs to reference its direct parent and not all parents in the hierarchy ..

so customer only needs to reference the city, city only the region, region only the country

```
SELECT
    Country_Table.Country,
    Region_Table.Region,
    City_Table.City,
    Count(Customer_Id) AS Customers
FROM
    Country_Table
    INNER JOIN Region_Table ON Region_Table.Country_Id = Country_Table.Country_Id
    INNER JOIN City_Table ON City_Table.Region_Id = Region_Table.Region_Id
    INNER JOIN Customer_Table ON Customer_Table.City_Id = City_Table.City_Id
GROUP BY
    Country_Table.Country,
    Region_Table.Region,
    City_Table.City
```

Comment: @Gaby, so you're saying the customer table doesnt need to have region and country fields?

Comment: The customer table doesn't need them if they are in the city table. Strictly the city table doesn't need the country if the region table has it. If you keep redundant data like this, sooner or later your database will contain contradictions.

Comment: @Zaki, yes because region can be found from the city table and country can be found from the region .. this works because its customer can only belong to a single city, a city to a single region and a region to a single country.. So each table only needs to reference the parent one and no other..

Comment: One more concern here, Ive been running one of the sql in the answers here and its takin a looong time, i mean its been more than 6-7 mins to get the result. Im using sql developer against Oracle 11g database on the server and customer_table having ~80,000 rows. what might be taking the query so long?

Comment: @zaki, you should have indexes on the city, region and country fields in their respective tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
select Country,Region,City,count(Customer_ID)
from Customer_table as cust
inner join  Country_table on Country_ID=cust.Country_ID
inner join Region_table on Region_ID=cust.Region_ID
inner join Region_table on City_ID=cust.City_ID
group by country,Region,City
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT Country, Region, City, COUNT(Customer_ID) as [no.of customers]
FROM Country_Table
INNER JOIN Region_Table ON Country_Table.Country_ID = Region_Table.Country_ID
INNER JOIN City_Table ON City_Table.Region_ID = Region_Table.Region_ID
INNER JOIN Customer_Table ON Customer_Table.City_ID = City_Table.City_ID
GROUP BY Country, Region, City;
```

Comment: The two `AND` clauses in your query are not needed.